# Email signature generated html table stretched vertically in Outlook 2010

Tags: html, outlook

I have written an email signature generator in PHP. The program spits out output in the following file format:

signature_file.htm

signature_style.css

signature_image_folder

The images and the stylesheet are linked within the htm file. This works when viewed in a web browser.

When I copy the files into the following path:

..\Documents and Settings\user_name\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures\

for the signature to show up in the signature manager in Outlook 2010, it appears just fine - with the fonts, images, etc. except the table which holds all the information is stretched vertically. It seems the rows' heights have been expanded to 100%.

Within the CSS file I have specified statically the table height, yet Outlook seems to be overriding it.

Also, when the signature is loaded from Outlook, it creates an *.rtf file. Within the rtf, the height is wrong as well.

Comment: could you share one example please? use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hi jackJoe, here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/nk9v5/

Comment: After checking you code, I can't really find a reason for that behaviour... What I recommend is to specify inline styles (yes, old-scholl), also specify heights for each `<td>` and even tables inside tables. Normally I don't rely on linked CSS for html emails.

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion. did that... it won't budge... :(

Comment: can you supply a screenshot of what you are seeing on the email? and point out where it is wrong? use something like http://imgur.com/ to share the image.

Comment: hi there, thanks for your interest and willingness to help! what it SHOULD look like and how it looks in a browser: https://skitch.com/master-p/r93n5/localhost-8888-podpisy-podpis.php what it SHOULD NOT look like and what it looks like in outlook 2010: https://skitch.com/master-p/r93dr/10.99.0.128 ...you see, in the latter it gets 'stretched' and the height of the table and cells increases. i've tried specifying it via an outside css file, with a <style> tag within the html file, and also with height attributes within the actual <td> tags in the html... all to the same effect! :(

Comment: ok, thanks, I'm going to make a test and find out what's causing that, but could you supply the html that is generated? the jsfiddle that you posted had php and I would like to see the actual html generated.

Comment: for sure, thanks!: http://jsfiddle.net/9Awtg/

Comment: @Piotr thanks for the code, I just posted my suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

For some reason Outlook doesn't understand layout styling such as padding. I had to Get rid of all heights of rows, columns etc, get rid of all padding and just have a 'squashed' table sized by solely its contents. Then where i needed some padding, i just 
 it as needed.

Unfortunately this was all for nothing (but knowledge), since in the end the marketing people at my work told me to use an uglier layout which doesn't use tables... For shame! :)
Thanks jackJoe for all your help! :D

Take care,
Piotr.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have some hints so that you can solve this.

(As you definitely know by now, Outlook is incredibly bad at dealing with html and it can do the most outrageous things even if it doesn't make sense).

So, my suggestions are:

1. Your table has a defined height:

   (`table#signature_table`) `height:
   450px;`

   You need to remove that height! The
   table will have whatever height it
   needs.
2. Then, most elements have a
   `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`
   (ex: `th#employee_name` and
   `th#employee_position`), try to
   change this via defining a height to
   the `<td>` of those elements; For
   example:

   If you had a padding-bottom: 20px,
   just make sure your `<td>` has
   enough height (with the text) to
   "stretch" it to the previous 20px,
   like `<td height=40>`. This needs to
   be tested until you get the right
   size.
3. Try to use pixels instead of points,
   point sizes are less "controllable";
4. Make sure you use inline styles
   (such as `style="font-size:
   11px;"`), this is a way to make sure
   the styles are being applied,
   especially with email clients that
   don't accept external CSS (Gmail,
   etc). Apply all the styles and don't
   forget adding a font-family to the
   table (at least). It is a waste of
   code but in the end it will be worth
   the extra code.
5. Simplify: Don't use table headers
   `<th>` and other tags like that
   (IMO), I only use `<tr>` and `<td>`
   that's it. I think Outlook can style
   `<th>` in ways not expected.
   Creating html emails means you need
   to code the html and css like you
   were in 1999, so don't mind using
   tables, etc. Make sure the code
   validates.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for all your help. Unfortunately, I've applied all of the suggestions but alas nothing made a difference. The code now validates, the heights for the cells are set inline, no padding is applied, and table has no height set... still the same thing... :( I am desperate at this point.

Comment: @Piotr Your code is not following my suggestion of using inline CSS... It should have the styles applied directly to the tags, like this `<td style="font-size: 11px;">` also, the height on a `<td>` element, needs to be defined without a unit, like this `<td height=30>`. Unless you apply the styles in an inline fashion, you'll probably keep having the same problems.

Comment: Hi again jackJoe, I have done it exactly as you said (I think): http://jsfiddle.net/sBAra/ still no dice! :(

Comment: ok, I just saw it, I'm out of ideas for now. I only have Outlook 2007 and it works there with a copy/paste from the browser window, that's my last suggestion, bu obviously it's nothing close to placing the signature files on the appropriate folder, although you could "build" the signature files via a copy/paste and save as signature, care to try that?

Comment: unfortunately the idea is to automate generating custom 'fancy' looking signatures for a firm... so that it looks exactly the same for everyone. this is needful as unfortunately some people are less tech-savvy than others. being called to 100+ people to configure signatures for each of them is a drag. this could be done with microsoft exchange, however that's something our workplace still hasn't invested in. so there is that... :(